# Redirect https://example.com to https://www.example.com Heroku/Namecheap

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, mern, namecheap

I have a domain I purchased through Namecheap and hosted with Heroku. I am using a Heroku automatically managed SSL Certificate. Currently when I go to https://mysite.io the request times out saying the site cannot be reached. http://mysite.io redirects to https://www.mysite.io with no issues. How would I go about redirecting the https://mysite.io URL?

My website is a SPA built on the MERN stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this issue was to add both the root domain (example.com) and the www domain (www.example.com) to Heroku. Prior to this I had only a CNAME Record with a 'www' host pointed to Heroku. Now I also have an ALIAS Record with the root host '@' pointed to Heroku.

Thanks to @Ed. Kenbers for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a DNS CNAME or A Record:

```
www CNAME example.com.
```

or

```
www A <YOUR-PUBLIC-IP>
```

www is a subdomain of example.com like login.example.com can be.

Comment: Hey Ed, thanks for the suggestions. I tried both of those fixes and the issue is still occurring. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I don't know about how Heroku manage it but If the DNS is configured, it seems like you don't have the virtual host configured in your http server. I found this documentation in heroku that can maybe help you. [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains).
It seems you have to add/remove domains/subdomains.

Comment: It can take time to DNS to propagate changes, to test it use on command line: 
`nslookup www.example.com` and `nslookup example.com`. They have to have the same response or similar. (one redirecting to the other)

Comment: Thanks for doing that legwork Ed. It appears to be an issue between namecheap and Heroku. I made a ticket and I am working with them now. All the best!