# Namecheap: Redirect https://example.com to https://WWW.example.com?

Tags: meteor, dns, namecheap

This duplicates [an identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62438029/redirect-https-example-com-to-https-www-example-com-heroku-namecheap) asked previously on SO.

However, the accepted answer there appears no longer to work. The accepted answer there is:

> Prior to this I had only a CNAME Record with a 'www' host pointed to
> Heroku. Now I also have an ALIAS Record with the root host '@' pointed
> to Heroku.

I tried to add an ALIAS record on Namecheap with host=='@', pointing to 'https://www.example.com'. But, Namecheap put up a message saying:

> Error occured: INVALID_ADDR : 'https://www.example.com' should not be
> an IP/ URL for ALIAS record.(host name: @)

I also tried an ALIAS record with host=='@', pointing to my web host (us-####-#.galaxy-ingress.meteor.com). Namecheap accepted that, but my web host said the Namecheap configuration was incorrect when I tried to generate an SSL certificate.

What's the correct way to do this on Namecheap?

Comment: I would use a CNAME

Comment: I think that's what Galaxy wants also. Namecheap docs say "NOTE: Please don't set up a CNAME record for a bare domain e.g., yourdomain.tld (@ hostname) since it may affect the operation of the domain's MX records and, consequently, the email service." I have an email in to Galaxy to ask if I can use an A record with @ and an IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment Meteor Galaxy requires a CNAME record, and as noted in the comment above, Namecheap doesn't want you to use a CNAME record for this. The solution, provided by Galaxy, was to use a third-party service. I won't post the url to the 3rd-party service here, as that might look like spam, but you can read about it in Galaxy's docs here:

https://galaxy-guide.meteor.com/dns.html#root-domain

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message when setting up Alias, it seems that https:// in the value field is the issue. Have you tried alias for @ as a host and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) as value?

Comment: I have. That worked for `http://example.com`, but not for `https://example.com`.